# Is it possible to invoke a Lambda function in a different AWS account from Secrets Manager rotation?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager

We are trying to make our Lambda function a centralize kind of thing which can be invoked by a secrets manager from different accounts. So Lambda app can be used across multiple accounts for the automatic rotation of secrets.

[image: Secrets Manager Rotation]
Basically in the image, we want to select a lambda function that is deployed to a different account.

Note: Secrets manager and Lambda Function are in the same region.

We have tried the steps below to achieve our goal but none of these have worked so far:

1. Grant access across different AWS accounts using IAM roles and assume role.
2. Add a resource based policy into function app